# Laravel very slow eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, execution-time

I need to get catalogs from database using Laravel query, so I write simply:

```
   $catalogs = Catalog::where('shop_id', $shop->id)->latest()->get(['id','title', 'created_at', 'shop_id', 'cover_bg', 'frontpage', 'pdf', 'clicks', 'finished']);
```

In a catalog table I have more than 100 columns - 2 of them are with type `longtext`. Catalog currently contain around 14000 records and fetching data is very slow:

Here is phpMyAdmin execution time

[image]

**Here is Laravel query execution time:**
[image]

How I can speed up my query? I think 14 000 records are not big table. Also as you can see I try to avoid my longtext columns so I didnt fetch them.

Is it problem with a server performance or something else?

Also CPU very low:
[image]

Comment: paginate the result. check what relations are loading. check if there are n+1 queries and php is a slow language

Comment: Remember that in the eloquent query you are also spinning up read/write models for every row. That adds a lot of overhead. Do you need all the models? Could you just make a raw query to get the data without making a collection of models?

Comment: You mean to use DB:: ?

Comment: $catalogs = DB::table('catalogs')
    ->select('id', 'title','frontpage','pdf')
    ->get(); the same results ...

Comment: this is my big concern: https://imgur.com/a/iCfX3Yl

Comment: 22 seconds is A LOT of time for a MySQL query for the number of records you have. Did you migrate all catalog records and have the same `created_at` value? Consider ordering by `id` and taking just 1 result instead of `->latest()` if that's the case.

Comment: Please provide the _generated_ SQL statement; we may be able to work backward from that.

Comment: I have the same issue, phpMyAdmin took less than 1 sec, while about 3s in Laravel, same query both paginated

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to using raw query, not Eloquent by using `DB::select(DB::raw('...'))`

Answer (score 0):

This is because something called N+1 Query Issue that rapidly increases the total queries ..

I recommend you to read this article

**https://laravel-news.com/laravel-n1-query-problems**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32807842)